# Spring MVC: Pass Object between Controllers Given URL

Tags: spring-mvc, controller, forward

I have a controller that passes a list of Song objects to a view.

This list is outputted as a list of URLs with the object's ID property in the URL:

e.g.

`http: //.../song/23` is obtained by:

```
<a href="song/${song.id}">   

<c:out value="${song.songName}"/>

</a>
```

Further details:

The question is what would be the correct way to forward the correct song object to the song controller that is responsible in generating the `...song/23` URL ?

Example: Looping through 4 song objects should produce a view with 4 links.

Link1
Link2
Link3
Link4

Each link corresponds to a song object and clicking on each link should forward to a unique URL. E.g.: if song1's id is 42 then clicking on Link1 should forward to http: //../song/42 and pass the song object corresponding to Link1 to the song controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can have some hidden variables in your form to fill them with  data when the song is selected and send to Controller from javascript function.

HTML:

```
<form method="POST" id="formId" action="">

    <input type="hidden" name="selectedSongId" value=""/>
    <input type="hidden" name="selectedSongName" value=""/>
    <input type="hidden" name="selectedSongArtist" value=""/>

    <c:forEach ...>
        <a href="submitForm(${song.id}, ${song.songName}, 
                            ${song.selectedSongArtist})">   
            <c:out value="${song.songName}"/>
        </a>
    </c:forEach>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
submitForm = function(songId, songName, songArtist){
    form = document.getElementById('formId');
    form.selectedSongId = songId;
    form.selectedSongName = songName;
    form.selectedSongArtist = songArtist;

    form.action="songs/"+songId+"/doSomething";
    form.submit();
}
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping("songs/{songId}/doSomething")
public String handleSubmit (@PathVariable String songId,
                  @RequestParam("selectedSongName") String songName,
                  @RequestParam("selectedSongArtist") String songArtist) {

    // do Something
}
```

This will do.

But, you can also fill the data in JSON object and send to Controller handler method having @ModelAttribute annotated argument. Google, if you are interested.